# DynamoDB Support to Arabic Language

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, arabic, arabic-support

Does Dynamo DB support Arabic language? If it does then how much foes it cost as money and performance in comparison with MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB attribute names are all [stored as UTF-8](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-naming-rules), as well as [String attribute values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-data-types). UTF-8 [supports Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages_3). DynamoDB pricing can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/).